# SOAP server at nodeJS failure with wsdl file

Tags: node.js, soap, wsdl

I have server in nodeJS using `soap` and don't know why sometimes my function work fine and sometimes doesn't even start.
If the problem occurred all the time it would be easier, but here it occurs sometimes.

I have xml from client app like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://framework.zend.com"><SOAP-ENV:Body><ns1:tokenVerify><appToken>6c580db45898d61</appToken><userId>1009</userId><token>0bc81d4aab68e9ca62f6cee6ee60300d</token><touch>true</touch></ns1:tokenVerify></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

and fail answer to client:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"  xmlns:tns="https://xxx/soap/server"><soap:Body><soap:Fault><soap:Code><soap:Value>SOAP-ENV:Server</soap:Value><soap:Subcode><soap:Value>InternalServerError</soap:Value></soap:Subcode></soap:Code><soap:Reason><soap:Text>TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading &apos;style&apos;)</soap:Text></soap:Reason></soap:Fault></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>
```

NodeJS soap server don't start even function `tokenVerify`!

Another client app try with some other data:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://framework.zend.com"><SOAP-ENV:Body><ns1:tokenVerify>
<appToken>b9549abc7bdb078</appToken><userId>1009</userId>
<token>07f5c563e559b6b89eb6606f15443500</token><touch>true</touch></ns1:tokenVerify></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

My function `tokenVerify` starts here, print some logs etc...
and answer to client:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"  xmlns:tns="https://xxx/soap/server"><soap:Body><tns:tokenVerifyResponse><tns:return>true</tns:return></tns:tokenVerifyResponse></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>
```

This two apps are on this same linux server with this same PHP in two different folders. (it's not my apps)

Heres my WSDL definition file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<definitions
    xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
    xmlns:tns="https://xxx/soap/server"
    xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:soap-enc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
    xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" 
    name="Cos_Service_Soap"
    targetNamespace="https://xxx/soap/server">
    <types>
        <xsd:schema targetNamespace="https://xxx/soap/server">
            <xsd:complexType name="Cos_Service_Type_UserInfo">
                <xsd:all>
                    <xsd:element name="login" type="xsd:string" nillable="true" />
                    <xsd:element name="email" type="xsd:string" nillable="true" />
                    <xsd:element name="displayAs" type="xsd:string" nillable="true" />
                </xsd:all>
            </xsd:complexType>
        </xsd:schema>
    </types>
    <portType name="Cos_Service_SoapPort">
 <operation name="tokenVerify">
            <documentation>Verify that the token given is still valid for a given user</documentation>
            <input message="tns:tokenVerifyIn" />
            <output message="tns:tokenVerifyOut" />
        </operation>
</portType>
<binding name="Cos_Service_SoapBinding" type="tns:Cos_Service_SoapPort">
 <soap:binding style="rpc" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" />
<operation name="tokenVerify">
            <soap:operation soapAction="https://xxx/soap/server#tokenVerify" />
            <input>
                <soap:body use="literal" namespace="http://framework.zend.com" />
            </input>
            <output>
                <soap:body use="literal" namespace="http://framework.zend.com" />
            </output>
        </operation>
<service name="Cos_Service_SoapService">
        <port name="Cos_Service_SoapPort" binding="tns:Cos_Service_SoapBinding">
            <soap:address location="https://xxx/soap/server" />
        </port>
    </service>
    <message name="tokenVerifyIn">
        <part name="appToken" type="xsd:string" />
        <part name="userId" type="xsd:int" />
        <part name="token" type="xsd:string" />
        <part name="touch" type="xsd:boolean" />
    </message>
    <message name="tokenVerifyOut">
        <part name="return" type="xsd:boolean" />
    </message>
</definitions>
```

cosservice.js file with tokenVerify function:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const cosServiceXml = fs.readFileSync(
    path.join(path.join(__dirname, 'wsdl'), 'cos_service_soap.wsdl'),
    'utf8'
);
const cosService = {
    Cos_Service_SoapService: {
        Cos_Service_SoapPort: {
 tokenVerify: async function (args, callback) {
                console.log(args);
 try { ... // all DB data etc...
   callback({ return: true });
} catch (error) {
...
module.exports = {
    service: cosService,
    xml: cosServiceXml,
};
```

Next in main app.js server file:

```
const soap = require('soap');
const cosService = require('./services/cosservice');

const cosWsdlPath = fs.readFileSync(
    './services/wsdl/cos_service_soap.wsdl',
    'utf-8'
);
app.all('/cos/soap/wsdl', function (req, res) { 
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/xml');
    res.end(cosWsdlPath);
});

const cosSoapServerWsdl = soap.listen(server, {
    path: '/soap/server',
    services: cosService.service,
    xml: cosService.xml,
    // soap12: false
});
cosSoapServerWsdl.log = function (type, data) {
    if (type === 'received') {
        console.log('Receive SOAP:');
        console.log(data);
    } else if (type === 'replied') {
        console.log('Send SOAP:');
        console.log(data);
    }
};
```

I was trying to change `tokenVerify` function to

```
tokenVerify: async function (args, callback) {
   callback({ return: true });
}
```

It didn't help. This function doesn't even start in the first case.
I also checked these client queries with API tester and there in both cases SOAP server return:

```
...
<tns:return>true</tns:return>
...
```